# How to add Drawable Resource in custom view

Tags: android

I am developing board game
We need to add images(from drawable folder) in custom view( extend view).

So that we don't have to define image views in main activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom view is expending `View` so either do:

```
view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.my_drawable );
```

Or:

```
if( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN ){
    view.setBackgroundDrawable( ContextCompat.getDrawable( context, R.drawable.my_drawable) );
}else {
    view.setBackground( ContextCompat.getDrawable( context, R.drawable.my_drawable) );
}
```

Comment: thanks done i use Drawable up = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_up),up.setBounds(6*d,top,7*d,(top+d));
      up.draw(canvas);